# Nginx "The page you were looking for doesn't exist" after switch to production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I´m trying to deploy a rails app to a VPS, using Ubuntu, Nginx and passenger.
Everything runs ok if I set things up on "**development**" mode, inside */etc/nginx/sites-enabled/testapp*:

```
passenger_app_env development;
```

As soon as I change to production mode and restart nginx, it starts to give me the ***"The page you were looking for doesn't exist"***

I checked access.log and error.log and there no new register after this error comes up.

Heres my sites-enabled/testapp:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name myvaliddomain.com; *#I´m actually using a valid domain here.*
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env production;
  root /home/hal/testapp/public;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: that error message might be misleading? check your rails production.log file for errors; my guess is the app is now connecting to the production database (which might not exist yet?)

Comment: what is the value of `RAILS_ENV` environment variable after deployment?

Comment: house9 was almost right. It was a silly database mistake. Although the production database was there, I did not run the latest migrations using RAILS_ENV = production, so they only existed on dev database. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

house9 was almost right. It was a silly database mistake. Although the production database was there, I did not run the latest migrations using RAILS_ENV = production, so they only existed on dev database. Thanks!

I just had to run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```